# Oracle Query to find out that the personnel uses different cards on the same day

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a staff table and each staff can have more than one card (in different types). But the staff can use a single card on the same day.

In the example, personnel used both cards on the same day or gave their card to someone else.

[image]

How can I write a query that can find this in Oracle?
Thanks.

Data

| Personel ID | Card Id | Card Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 1 |
| 1 | 222 | 2 |
| 2 | 333 | 2 |
| 3 | 444 | 1 |
| 3 | 555 | 2 |
| 4 | 666 | 1 |
| 4 | 777 | 2 |

| ID | Card Id | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 18.12.2022 |
| 2 | 222 | 18.12.2022 |
| 3 | 444 | 18.12.2022 |
| 4 | 222 | 19.12.2022 |
| 5 | 111 | 19.12.2022 |
| 6 | 444 | 19.12.2022 |
| 7 | 222 | 20.12.2022 |
| 8 | 666 | 20.12.2022 |
| 9 | 111 | 21.12.2022 |
| 10 | 666 | 21.12.2022 |

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text. Show the DDL of the tables involved, sample data for those tables and the result you want to achieve based on your sample data

Comment: Please read this topic and edit your question accordingly: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- apply a `JOIN` operation to match the two tables,
- aggregate on same ("*PersonelId*", "*Date*") pairs,
- filter out "*PersonelId*" values having only one appearance in every day
- get these values distinctively (if the same person has used different own cards in different days, that person would appear more than once)

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.PersonelId
FROM       entrances e
INNER JOIN cards c
        ON e.CardId = c.CardId
GROUP BY c.PersonelId, Date_
HAVING COUNT(c.PersonelId) > 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BJ04EsYc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNT(DISTINCT CardId) for each personnel and date, and check if more than one cardid was used:

```
select c.PersonelId
    , e.Date_
from #cards c
     inner join
     #entrances e
     on c.CardId=e.CardId
group by c.PersonelId, e.Date_
having count(distinct e.CardId) > 1
```